# Cannot install R in Ubuntu 20.04 in Windows 10

Tags: package-management, system-installation

I just downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04 WSL in Windows 10, however, I cannot install R. In view of this, I have tried to install build-essential, but it is still unsuccessful as the cpp, gcc, g++ cannot be installed as well.

[image]

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection. The screenshot shows connection failed, so check your internet connection. Here are some tips:

- Turn off any VPN.
- Turn off Windows Firewall in Windows Security.
- Check your router or wifi connection.
- Make sure that you have not set a static IP.
- Make sure that you dont have an `http://archive.ubuntu.com` entry in your `hosts` file that is located under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.
- Also, check the `/etc/hosts` file in your Ubuntu installation.

I hope that this information will be useful to you and other people who are visiting this question.

Comment: Sorry, I still encountered the same problem after following your instruction.
1. Turn off windows firewall
2. wifi connection set to private, IP setting: Automatic (DHCP) and random hardware address: on
3. I have checked the host files, no any ubuntu files